# AWS Fargate CannotPullContainerError

Tags: containers, amazon-ecs

I'm using AWS ECS to practice and I met this issue when launching my task, it failed with the reason:

```
CannotPullContainerError: inspect image has been retried 5 time(s): failed to resolve ref "docker.io/vaultwarden/server:latest": failed to do request: Head https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/vaultwarden/server/manifests/latest: dial tcp 3.226.210.61:443: ...
```

In task definition I'm using the image url from docker hub which i believe is an official image(`docker.io/vaultwarden/server:latest`
)

After doing some research, I checked my **VPC**, **subnet**(can access public internet), **IAM**, and tried whether enable **auto assign public IP** or disable it when I created the service, also I compared my task definition with my colleague and can't tell the difference, but his working fine.

After that, I tried to delete everything, cluster, service, task definition, etc and even switched my aws account to anther zone(from California to Oregon) and tried from scratch.

Finally I still get this same error, is my account been blocked for some reasons or anyone can provide some helps to me? I really appreciate that!

Comment: However, this is an "Cannot pull container" error, if im doing any unnecessary checks regarding this, please just ignore it :)

Comment: looks like error happens because of network configuration. It is hard to find exact problem without knowing all configuration (VPC, Network rules, NAT Gateway parameters, Security groups, ECS task definition). Maybe this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-pull-container-error/) will help you

Comment: Hi rzlvmp, i've read most of the articles from google and tried including this one, but it seems like still not able to work

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? Are you able to post a sanitized version of the working config?